# Xamarin: error MT1108: Could not find developer tools for this 11.0.3 (15A432) device

Tags: xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xcode9

I started to have this issue once I upgraded my phone to iOS 11.0.3.

It seems that now Visual Studio Community Edition for Mac (v7.2 build 636)

I've tried with both with XCode v9.0 (9A235) and v9.0.1 (9A1004)

This is the error that I receive in the application output in Visual Studio for Mac:

"error MT1108: Could not find developer tools for this 11.0.3 (15A432) device. Please ensure you are using a compatible Xcode version and then connect this device to Xcode to install the development support files."

I've verified that the path is set correctly for xcode-select, so in theory, it should work correctly. I'm almost thinking that the Xamarin toolchain does not yet support iOS v11.0.3

I've also tried deleting the bin/obj folders to no avail.

Might anyone be able to confirm that the Xamarin toolchain is compatible with iOS v11.0.3, and if so are there any special steps that need to be taken to make the toolchain recognize the version?

I can potentially downgrade my device to v11.0.1, but before I do I'd like to know if the toolchain is indeed incompatible.

Please let me know if there is more information that I can provide.

Comment: Did you try to delete the bin and obj folder ?

Comment: have you launched XCode?  Sometimes it prompts for you to accept a license agreement, or install additional cmd line tools

Comment: Yes, have tried deleting bin+obj, as well as starting Xcode (and uninstalling and reinstalling a lower version...) unfortunately no effect.

Comment: I'm also having this problem. I'm at a standstill for development. I've launched xcode and made sure everything was up to date, deleted all obj/bin files and restarted and made sure I'm on the latest Visual Studio (Mac) and all packages have been updated. I'm at a loss here.

Comment: Could you pastebin the complete version information from Visual Studio for Mac's About menu (click on Show Details to get everything)?

Answer (score 7):

Apple ships some extra development code for devices when it release Xcode (an additional disk image to be loaded by the operating system).

In general Xcode ships them for everything it support at that point of time. Which means that when a newer version of iOS is shipped **after** the Xcode release the missing disk image might be unavailable until an updated Xcode is released (Apple can't guarantee future compatibility of the disk image).

E.g. for Xcode 9.0 (I don't have 9.0.1 installed)

`/Applications/Xcode9.app/Contents//Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/11.0 (15A372)/DeveloperDiskImage.dmg`

Xamarin.iOS tries to load the image based on the device version. If it cannot find it it will report the [MT1108](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/troubleshooting/mtouch-errors/#MT1108_Could_not_find_developer_tools_for_this_XX_YY_device.) error. A *potential* workaround would be to rename (or copy) the disk image to match your iOS version number. YMMV depending on the changes that Apple introduced in that iOS update.

Note that Xamarin.iOS does not need the disk image for most features. The most visible one, where it's required, is to automatically start the application on devices.

As you found out the deployment works and you can manually start the application and the debugger will connect. I'll update the [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/troubleshooting/mtouch-errors/#MT1108_Could_not_find_developer_tools_for_this_XX_YY_device.) to include this information.

**Update**

There was no further Xcode 9.0.x release after iOS 11.0.3. However the next Xcode release (9.1) included support for all 11.0.x versions.

`/Applications/Xcode91.app/Contents//Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/11.0/DeveloperDiskImage.dmg`

The `shasum` of both images are identical so you can assume the one from Xcode9.0 could be renamed/copied without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to project folder and delete folders named bin & obj. That should fix the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, that has no effect on the issue.

Comment: Update: Well on a whim I tried manually launching the application after the error came up and -- Viola! -- it started debugging normally. Not ideal at all, but at least a work around I can live with for the moment. @VincilBishop, can you give this a try and see if it works for you too?

Comment: Thanks @Ethan, yes that does work. I'd almost be furious and declare working without a debugger is unacceptable, but then I remember that the client somehow broke the debugger in the app and breakpoints don't work...I guess that's a topic for another SO question, LOL

Comment: I was actually able to debug as well. Just start debugging and when the error comes up on the console manually launch the app and the debugger attaches just like normal.